# Loading data from Postgres dump into new db within Docker Postgres Container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm moving an application from Heroku into Docker containers, and am trying to figure out how to migrate the data from my Heroku db into my new Postgres container.

**Attempt so far**

I have copied a dump of the db into the Postgres container.

```
docker cp latest.dump mycontainer:/latest.dump
```

However when I try to pg_restore it, I'm getting errors as I attempt to run a docker exec command.

```
docker exec <pg_container> pg_restore -d <db_name> latest.dump

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "<db_name>" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Or when I try to run with the db user:

```
docker exec <pg_container> -u <db_user> pg_restore -d <db_name> latest.dump

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-u\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to go about loading this data into the new database within the docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution as a one line command:

```
docker exec <container_name> pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h postgres --dbname=postgresql://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:<port>/<db_name> latest.dump
```

latest.dump is the name of my db dump from Heroku so that can be changed to whatever the name of your dump is.